# Error occurs when inserting values

Tags: asp.net

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string connString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=test_db;Integrated Security=True;";
     string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO empDetl (empName,addr) values(@empName,@addr)";

     string _name = txtName.Text;
     string _addr = txtAddr.Text;
     using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
     {
       //open DB Connection
       conn.Open();
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn))
       {
           cmd.Parameters.Clear();
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empName", _name);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr", _addr);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       conn.Close();
     }
 }
```

This code doesn't work properly. Please tell me where the error is. While inserting values it says "Invalid object name 'empDetl'" but my table name is empDetl.

Comment: make sure `test_db` database contains `empDetl` table

Comment: Please ensure that table 'empDetl' exist in your database.

Comment: What schema does `empDetl` belong to? I assume it's not `dbo`. Then you need `INSERT INTO schemaName.empDetl`

Comment: thanks for the help. any way do u know how to set sql connection using proxy.if you know please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a database security issue here.

```
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=test_db;Integrated Security=True;";
```

This is going to use the current windows user (in the case of a web application probably the IIS user or whatever user your application runs under) to connect to the database using windows authentication.

Although your table may exist, the connecting user may not be able to see it.

Try change your connection string to the same user credentials you are connecting to your DB with through management studio

```
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=test_db;User Id=sa;Password=********;";
```

Comment: thanks for the help. any way do u know how to set sql connection using proxy.if you know please help me.